Extensions preserving Lipschitz constant
Let $f:K \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ function defined on the set $K=[0,1]^2$ (more generally, $K$ could be a convex and compact set in $\mathbb{R}^d$) such that $f$ and its derivatives are pointwise-bounded. Due to the latter assumption, $\nabla f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous with constant $L$, say in the $\ell_2$ norm. Notice that we are not assuming any convexity on $f$.
My question is:
Can we extend $f$ and $\nabla f$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the gradient of the extension, call it $\nabla\mathcal{E}(f)$ still displays the same Lipschitz constant?
I think the answer is affirmative due to the regularity of $f$ (and the pointwise bounds) and would be essentially an extension of [1], but I am a bit unsure about how to justify it.

What do you mean by "pointwise bounded"? I only know how it makes sense for a sequence of functions

By pointwise bounded I refer that $f$ and its derivatives are bounded in $L^\infty$; in other words, for every partial derivative $g_\alpha = \frac{\partial f^\alpha }{\partial x^\alpha} $ (with $\alpha$ a multiindex), then there exists two constants $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a \leq g_\alpha \leq b$.

The Lipschitz constant of $\nabla\mathcal{E}(f)$ might have to be greater than $L=\sup f'(K)$. In the one-dimensional case, where $K=[k_1,k_2]$, you can make an example where $f'(k_2)=L>0$ and $f''(k_2)>0$. So, slightly beyond $x=k_2$, the derivative of $f$ would exceed $L$.
Well, to arrive at $\nabla\mathcal{E}(f)$, start by extending $f$ to a smooth $g$, which is on this link: Is it possible to extend an arbitrary smooth function on a closed subset of $R^n$ to a smooth function on $R^n$?
(I don't know how to prove it, but I was able to find the reference.)
Then, to bound the gradient:
Let $N$ be greater than the maximum distance of $K$ from the origin.
Create a smooth function $j(x)$ which attains only $1$ for all $x<N^2$ and which attains only $0$ for all $x>(N+1)^2$.
Let $J(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=j(x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2)$.
Now, $g\times J$ gives you the required extension.
